# DolphinDB: Check if a value already exists before updating data

Tags: in-memory-database, dolphindb

I’m trying to import a new in-memory table to a distributed table. My purpose is to  update the record if a value already exists and write it if it doesn’t exist. What can I use to fulfill it?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using function upsert! The steps are illustrated as follows:

First create a distributed database and write data to the database for the first time:

```py
if (existsDatabase("dfs://rangedb128"))
{
    dropDatabase("dfs://rangedb128")
}
db=database("dfs://rangedb128", VALUE,  0..10)

ID=0 1 2 2
x=0.1*0..3
t=table(ID, x)

pt=db.createPartitionedTable(t, `pt, `ID)
pt.append!(t)
select * from pt
```

The result is:

| ID | x |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0.1 |
| 2 | 0.2 |
| 2 | 0.3 |

Write data to the database for the second time:

```py
t1=table([1,5] as ID, [111,555] as x)
upsert!(pt, t1, keyColNames=`ID)
select * from pt;
```

The updated result is:

| ID | x |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 111 |
| 2 | 0.2 |
| 2 | 0.3 |
| 5 | 555 |

As you can see, the value of x when ID = 1 is updated and the value of x when ID = 5 is added.